# Ethereum : Am I mining to my correct wallet address?

Tags: ethereum, wallet, metamask

I'm trying to start Ethereum, so I created my wallet first using metamask and I added to geth using private key with this command.

```
geth account import private_key.txt
```

After that I run the mining command using `geth --mine`, so my question is : am I really mining to my correct wallet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1:**
You can set the account your Ethereum miner mines to by running the following in the geth console:

```js
miner.setEtherbase('yourethaddress')
```

You can also set a local address to mine to using:

```js
miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[2])
```

Replace '2' with the number of your account.

**OPTION 2:** When starting your geth node you can use the `--etherbase` flag.

```sh
geth --rpc --etherbase 0xC95767AC46EA2A9162F0734651d6cF17e5BfcF10
```

Using your ETH public address.

More information here: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/mining

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, can I know the difference between the two options? that I need to do those steps in each `geth` running or the option 1 is for remembering the account?

Comment: @sayou Either will work completely fine. (Only one is required) By the sounds of what you're doing, I would recommend using the second option. If you decide to use the first one though, you can enter the geth console with `geth attach`.

Comment: Thanks, sir for all your information, but I have one last question - if you want - I read the documentation of `geth` (the link in your comment) and I found that I need to download `ethminer`, but for me, I just did the two steps above (create the wallet, install geth) Is this enough for me or should I download the `ethminer`? (Sorry for the inconvenience, but I'm still very new to the field)

Comment: @sayou No problem! Ask as many questions as you need :) - You shouldn't need to download `ethminer` as you can just CPU mine. Running either of the two commands and start mining and you should be good to go! Note: you can also start the mining process in the geth console with `miner.start()`

Comment: Thanks really for your help sir, can I know when my wallet can get currency? Just to make sure that everything works? Simply how long might it take?

Comment: Really depends on your CPU power. You can enter your hash rate on this website to calculate how much money you'll make: https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/eth?HashingPower=&HashingUnit=KH%2Fs&PowerConsumption=140&CostPerkWh=0&MiningPoolFee=0 - as for how long until your first payment, it can be anywhere from a few hours to a few weeks. You may even get lucky and mine a whole block ;)